# Why do i get this error "operator does not exist: json ->> unknown" in postgres when querying data from json object

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql

I have been trying to query data from my server PHPpgAdmin database but i always get error unlike when i use local posgres database on my laptop. See the code below:

```
pool.query(`select file from "coverphoto" where info ->> 'customID' = '${data}'`)
```

Error I get after query:

```
error: operator does not exist: json ->> unknown
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home3/akpulufa/nodevenv/oppra-news-app/16/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
at Parser.handlePacket (/home3/akpulufa/nodevenv/oppra-news-app/16/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
at Parser.parse (/home3/akpulufa/nodevenv/oppra-news-app/16/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home3/akpulufa/nodevenv/oppra-news-app/16/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

i need answers urgenly please.

Comment: What is this `->>`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: the version: PostgreSQL 9.2.24

Comment: @ChineduFabian - this Json operator available after version PostgreSQL 9.3